# How to apply a test for a whole collection or folder?

Tags: postman

I have a collection with a couple of folders. I would like to run a test for all the requests on a given folder or collection. It's a simple response time test, but it's quite annoying to copy/paste for each request this test. Is there anyway to run a test for all requests on a folder or collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had it straight from a Postman's developer on their Slack channel: there's no such feature, but might be interesting to have it.

I hope it helps. I also hope it helps to make people think twice and giving it a try to understand the question before downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the runner for this.

Check out the documentation on that here: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/running_collections

Comment: Could you please point which part of the mentioned documentation contains the answer for my question? I've read that already before posting here, just did it again and still can't find the solution for my problem.

Comment: Sorry that I misunderstood your question. I thought you were interested in running only a subfolder of a collection.

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature request ticket for this (about 1 year old)
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2247

But I found a workaround on this thread
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/882

The dlopuch post gives a working solution.
You store your test methods into a variable. and when you need a test you just get the variable and eval it. You then have an object with all your tests functions on it.

I tried and it works fine.